# Customizing django-allauth password_reset_from_key template

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using django 2.2.3, I'm overriding django-allauth templates and on password_reset_from_key template I came across a NoReverseMatch Exception,

```
Reverse for 'account_reset_password_from_key' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$']
```

So it expects argument and probably that argument is the key that is generated during resetting password. From the URL pattern, 'key' is the variable's name

I tried to pass it with 'key'.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'account_reset_password_from_key' key %}">
...
</form>
```

but it did not work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not overriding the allauth view, then use `action_url`:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action_url }}">
```

that's what the view passes to the template.

Comment: When I try that, I get TemplateSyntaxError saying it's not valid block tag.

Comment: sorry, typo. it's a variable not a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply where that error is coming from, but if I look for where that url name is used in the code, it's not being used in a template.

See: 
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/search?q=account_reset_password_from_key&unscoped_q=account_reset_password_from_key

My guess is you're calling this [url name](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/41f84f5530b75431cfd4cf2b89cd805ced009e7d/allauth/account/urls.py#L29-L31) and not passing the parameters to it?

```
    url(r"^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$",
        views.password_reset_from_key,
        name="account_reset_password_from_key"),
```

PS:

As a general rule when overriding django app templates I'd suggest starting with the original template (eg copy the file `allauth/templates/account/password_reset.html` or whatever to your `templates` dir (creating all the subdirectories)), and then change the pieces you need - that way if something goes wrong it's easy to roll back and figure out why.

I know from experience that allauth templates are fairly complex and it's easy to break functionality in them if you don't fully understand how they work.

Comment: Yes I am pointing to that URL by name, tried to pass 'key' as a parameter but it didn't work.